# IF function in Excel using data from 2 columns

Tags: excel

I want to create a third column that will mark true if the following criteria is met.

1) the AB number in column 1 is repeated, and the date in column 2 is the same for the repeated AB numbers. for example, the last two rows display the same number (AB15205045) on the same date (10/28/14). I would like the column next to this to be marked. is that possible?

```
    AB15205030  10/28/14 
    AB15205031  10/28/14 
    AB15205032  10/28/14 
    AB15205033  10/28/14 
    AB15205040  10/28/14 
    AB15205041  10/28/14 
    AB15205044  10/28/14 
    AB15205045  10/28/14 
    AB15205045  10/28/14
```

Answer (score 0):

=COUNTIFS(A:A,A2,C:C, C2)>1 achieves the correct answer.